# Auth Component's user function not working in case multiple routing

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I have routed my site as admin moderator. Means When I use Auth component my sessions are created as `Auth->Admin->id` & `Auth->Moderator->id` And `Auth->User->id` this way.

Now I tried function `$this->Auth->user` its returning null why??

As I know `$this->Auth->user` returns session.

I know the traditional way of `$this->Session->reads('Auth.Admin')` and else but I want to use Auth->user function why its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this to get user session data.

```
public function login() {
 if ($this->request->is('post')) {
     if ($this->Auth->login()) {
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
     } else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
     }
 }
}

public function index() {
    pr($this->Auth->User());
}
```

Comment: I have just used the same tag. I have just skipped function curly braces in my above code.. Else using this also returns null.

Comment: did you used the same code as above if not please add your code for login so we can check

Answer (score 0):

```
        auth_helper:<?php
        defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

        if ( ! function_exists('auth'))
        {
            function auth()
            {
                $CI =& get_instance();
                $CI->load->model('Auth_model');
                return $CI->Auth_model;
            }

            function Adminauth($admin_id) 
            {
                if($admin_id == false)
                {
                    redirect('login');
                }
            }
        }
    auth_model:
    <?php
    if (!defined('BASEPATH')) {
        exit('No direct script access allowed');
    }

    class Auth_model extends CI_Model {
        private $user = null;
        private $ci = null;

        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $CI =& get_instance();
            $this->ci = $CI;
        }

        public function get($name, $default = null){
            if ($this->ci->session->has_userdata('auth.Adminuser_id')) {
                 $user_id = $this->ci->session->userdata('auth.Adminuser_id');
                 $this->user = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE u_id=? LIMIT 1", array($user_id))->row();
            }

            return !empty($this->user) ? $this->user->u_name : $default;
        }
        public function is_logged(){
            return $this->ci->session->has_userdata('auth.Adminuser_id');
        }
        public function login($user_id){
            return $this->ci->session->set_userdata('auth.Adminuser_id', $user_id);
        }
        public function logout(){
            return $this->ci->session->unset_userdata('auth.Adminuser_id');
        }
    }
```